# Git: remote: fatal: index file corrupt, "index uses yz extension"?

Tags: wordpress, git

I have just encountered an issue I have never seen before and can't find any help on.

I run a git master repo on the live website in our hosting environment, and a bare origin repo on the same server. All our developer commits go to the bare origin master, which has a post-receive hook to push each commit to the master repo so that the push is reflected in the live site files. The only annoyance is that whenever we get WordPress updates, we have to commit on the master repo, then push it back to the origin repo so that our developers can download those updated files.

Problem: Today, I went to commit a WordPress plugin update, and the commit worked fine, but the push gave the following cryptic error that I cannot find any help on:

```
git push origin master

Counting objects: 344, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (323/323), done.
Writing objects: 100% (344/344), 1.76 MiB | 5.61 MiB/s, done.
Total 344 (delta 237), reused 14 (delta 1)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (237/237), completed with 226 local objects.
remote: Running post-receive (git pull origin master):
remote: error: index uses ▒yz▒ extension, which we do not understand
remote: fatal: index file corrupt
```

(The weird symbols around the letters "yz" reads as "`<B3>yz<AC>`" when I run git diff)

If I run `git status` on master (cannot be run on origin as it is a bare repo), it repeats the last two lines of output. If I run `git log` on both repos, they look normal, but the origin is of course one commit behind the master, because committing to master worked, but pushing to origin failed.

I have never heard of this "yz" extension before, and as far as I can tell, no one else has either. All I did was a commit and a push and the push failed. We do not use any such "yz" extension, we use vanilla Git, do very basic pushes and pulls, our post-receive hook is about a 5 line script which just auto-pushes every commit from origin to master and resets file permissions to ensure they're readable by the web server. The only weird thing we're doing is using Git to manage a WordPress site for version control. All developers use TortoiseGit on Windows without any special settings or any sort of plugins.

I have seen plenty of questions and answers about corrupt indexes, but nothing like this.

I have not tried anything yet as I'm not sure what to do, don't understand the internals of Git, and don't want to break anything, but we need to be able to pull and push and cannot until the repos are in sync again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here's what I did:

Because I did not want to lose any changes to the master repo (corrupt index), as the changes needed to be kept and also pushed to origin (working index), I ran the following:

```
rm .git/index
git reset --mixed
```

(mixed is the default option)

According to the documentation:

```
--mixed
Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.
```

Thanks to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) and [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204) for your help in understanding the situation, and a little bit of googling to figure out the safest process for resetting an index without losing any committed or working files

Comment: Same exact thing happened again! I guess Git doesn't like being a repo for a WordPress site where hundreds of files get updated every few days until the entire thing balloons up into the multiple gigabytes!

Answer (score 2):

Everything prefixed with `remote:` came not from *your* Git but from *their* Git—the Git your Git called up, at the URL you used when you ran `git push`.

It's *their Git* that is complaining about *their Git's index*.  This is probably a file corruption issue on their machine.  You need to get them—whoever "they" are—to check out their system.  If all looks OK, they should probably just remove and rebuild their index files.

(If "they" / "them" is really you, go over to whichever machine(s) are involved, inspect them carefully for damage or disks that are on fire or whatever, and if all looks good, remove and rebuild the index files.)

Comment: Both repos are on the same machine which I have full control of. when I run "git status" on the live website repo that is serving files to the Internet, I get the erorr, and the origin repo is fine, but is missing the latest commit. The server is a virtual server running on a RAID 10 with 4 drives which is perfectly fine, so I guess I will pursue trying to rebuild the index. Do you have any insight as to what this "yz" extension thing means?

Comment: The Git index file supports a variety of extensions, such as ones for split index and untracked cache, and they're all typed by four-byte values.  0xb3797aac is not a valid extension, and Git doesn't know if it's safe to ignore, so it fails.

Comment: is there a way i can revert the repo files back to the previous commit without losing all the actual source files which have changed since, or rebuild the index of the master repo without changing any source files or otherwise dropping the master repo out of sync with its origin repo?

Comment: I got it fixed. standard index rebuild handled it as you said, after backing up the repo just in case. Thanks guys!

Comment: @RedScourge: I've been AFK but I see you got it handled. It's still very odd to see a junk "extension" value in the index file: what put it there?

Comment: @torek based on what bk2204 says it sounds like the part of the index that corrupted itself includes the part where it may store what type of index it is, which I assume means that the Git code was built to allow different index types, perhaps in case someone invented a more efficient one in the future.

Comment: The index format is documented (not terribly well) [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt), if you want to investigate further.